# Dynamic CRM Connector not showing all Marketing List

Tags: dynamics-crm-module, crm

I am using Sitecore 10.2 with `Dynamic CRM Connector`, I run two pipelines

1. Dynamics Marketing Lists to xDB Reference Sync
2. Dynamics Marketing Lists to xConnect Sync

Both pipelines are working fine with no errors, but when I go to list the manager and create a segmented list then add the rule `where contact is a member of specific list from the Dynamics tenant specific`, I can not see all lists which is available in CRM.

[image]

Comment: Are you storing the lists in xDB? Can you see them in there? Otherwise, I suspect it could be a field mapping issue. Perhaps in your pipeline you could add a logging step.

Comment: @MarcelGruber I am using OOTB pipeline which is available in dynamic CRM connector and I can see facet of marketing list in xDB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be a bit tricky to help with these issues without being familiar with the individual set up (more screenshots / URLs are always appreciated). The following additional information would help:

- Where you are creating this rule
- Screenshots of the pipeline batches / pipeline steps
- Screenshots / examples of the relevant info in xDB (particularly the data formats)

For clarity, it sounds like you're creating a segmented list in the [List Manager](https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/users/102/sitecore-experience-platform/the-list-manager.html) based on a rule and you don't see all of the lists that you're expecting.

Note that I only have access to a 9.3 instance at the moment.

### Please verify / note / perform the following:

- You do not see any errors in the logs of the connector, Solr, Sitecore, or XConnect
- The correct tenant is selected in the rule (I notice that yours says "Branch" -- is it possible that you selected the branch template instead of the instantiated item?)
- Make note of any differences between the lists that you do see vs. the ones that you don't
- That the ID specified in your rule matches the format in the database or in any DEF config item(s)
- Nothing is "stuck" in your staging database
- Try to replicate the issue on a fresh install of XP + Connector
- Check if Solr has the data you're expecting
- You have members stored in xDB and their facets are populated
- You can see the contacts in Experience Profile
- Create a new tenant and start over
- Decompile and step through the relevant code
- Troubleshoot by using the List Manager API https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/92/sitecore-experience-manager/the-list-manager-api.html
- Only contact lists can be used as a list source. If you want to use a segmented list as a list source, you must first convert the segmented list to a contact list (this is mentioned in the Sitecore docs).
- If a contact list is created but not activated, you can activate it as part of the workflow by changing the Draft state to Deployed (this is mentioned in the Sitecore docs).
- Contact list definitions appear in the index only when they are activated using the Marketing Operations API or they are saved with the activated flag set to True (this is mentioned in the Sitecore docs).
- Do the following:

  - Deploy marketing definitions
  - Populate Solr Managed Schema
  - Reindex
  - Restart IIS

Comment: Thanks, I tried to create new tenant which is working fine

Comment: Interesting. I have run into other unrelated issues that were also resolved by creating a new tenant. I mentioned it to Sitecore in a ticket, so there could be a bug somewhere... Hard to replicate, though...